# how to terminate actions using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In my image puzzle that I'm attempting to get working, I want to move the mouse cursor to a specific place if the puzzle validation fails.  I've made some JavaScript code to be called when the mouse is dragged and dropped.  Is there any way to cancel this mouse movement?  Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
else if (temp == 9 && validate == false) {
    if (vl == 6 || vl == 8 || vl == 9) {
        var theData = theEvent.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        var theDraggedElement = document.getElementById(theData);
        theEvent.target.appendChild(theDraggedElement);
        theEvent.preventDefault();
        temp = vl;
    } else {
        alert("invalied move..");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `theEvent.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: not working with this code. do u know another way to do it.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

There isnt a single command if you want to support multiple browsers unfortunately. Try the following:

```
if (!e){
  e = window.event;
}
e.stopPropagation();
e.cancelBubble = true;
```

the `if (!e)` line checks to see if e is set, as some browsers don't pass the event argument to the method.